# If application is deployed in one timezone, how does using 'timestamp with time zone' works? - Psql

Tags: sql, timestamp, psql

I have a web application in java that is deployed using tomcat on a linux server.
My database is postgres.

I have a functionality in the application where users can upload attachments/file. I save the file information in data base(file name, file upload time and so on). I save the file upload time using 'timestamp without a time zone'.

1) On reading this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59006/what-is-a-valid-use-case-for-using-timestamp-without-time-zone), i was thinking is it a good practice for me to use 'timestamp without a time zone'?  My application does not care about converting from one time zone to another. For me, it does not matter where the user is located.

2) Suppose i switch to 'timestamp with a timezone', on file upload by a user, the server only has its own time. How will it convert it to different time zones(users time zone)?

Comment: store all dates and times as UTC or with UTC offsets, present them in whatever timezone suits.

Comment: How can i do that in postgres. On my windows system, postgres is using the system time and not the UTC time.

Comment: looking at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html I reckon you should be using `timestampz`